# Is pre-authentication against a second url supported in kafka-connect-http?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use ready made kafka connector for fetching the data from the REST API. I found kafka-connect-http connector on the confluent hub but this connector does not support pre-authentication of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised this as an issue in the (https://github.com/castorm/kafka-connect-http) and got the response that unfortunately this feature is not supported in the existing code of the connector. So if you have the implementation of the API without authentication then this is the readymade solution for you else you can go for streams etc.
Although the author had agreed that he will look into this feature in the coming future.